# UIB Date Picker- Display previous day instead of present date (Plunker attached)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

Plunker- http://plnkr.co/edit/RVKzD9kXNNxinShK7nLU?p=preview

I have a plunker which has the date displayed and a small icon where we can select any date we want and it will update it in the input field.

My problem is - i need to display the previous day when user opens the page. Currently here it displays presnt working day.

Also, while selecting previous day, i need not include weekends. i.e. saturday and sunday should be ignored. For e.g. today is 11th April. For previous date selection, i want 8th April to directly show up. 9th and 10th being saturday and sunday should be ignored.

Can someone please have a look.

Please ignore the below html code as it didnt allow me to post the question until i write some code. The plunker has the code which i am using.

```
<!doctype html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking the date.getDay() and decrementing accordingly.

```
 $scope.today = function () {
        var lastWorking=new Date();
        lastWorking.setDate(lastWorking.getDate()-1)
        // 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday
        while(lastWorking.getDay()==0 || lastWorking.getDay()==6){
          lastWorking.setDate(lastWorking.getDate()-1);
        }
        $scope.tradeDate = lastWorking;

    };
```

[Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9DKJUJkbvUG6IYf1mgi?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Narian. This is wat i was trying to get.